# Separate Spark AWS Glue Metastore entries by environment (test vs prod)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I plan to run my Spark SQL jobs on AWS's EMR, and I plan to use AWS's Glue Metastore to persist tables' schema and file location metadata. The problem I'm facing is I'm not sure how to isolate our test vs prod environments. There are times when I might add a new column to a table, and I want to test that logic in the test environment before making the change to production. It seems that the Glue Metastore only supports one entry per database-table pair, which means that test and prod would point to the same Glue Metastore record, so whatever change I make to the test environment would also immediately impact prod. How have others tackled this issue?

Comment: Why not create different database for test and prod environment?

Comment: The tables in glue catalogue are pointing to S3 data or RDS tables?

Comment: @HarshBafna They point to S3 tables. Changing the names of my databases would make the code different between prod and test and would somewhat defeat the purpose of the test environment.

Comment: You should make the database configurable in your code. Also, the test environment should be completely independent from the prod environment. It's certainly not a good idea for some other environment to point to the prod data.